# Extend an existing git repository and periodically, selectively, merge in updates from the main project

Tags: git, github

We are planning on customizing an open-source git project, and periodically we *may* want to pull in changes that the main project makes into our customized project. None of the options I can think of for doing this seem great.

For full clarity, we are customizing a blog/CMS template (https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper)

***Option 1: Fork the main repository, sync it periodically***

This seems the most obvious option. We'll fork the main repository, then create a branch `custommaster` to do our own custom work in. We can sync the main project to our fork periodically, and then create a PR for `master` to `custommaster` to merge in changes from the main repository.

**Downsides**

- We start out with a repository which has a ton of existing history, branches, tags, etc. As opposed to a clean new repository that we can tag v1.0.0 as our first customization to the blog is made, only have our own branches/tags/commit history in the repo
- Anytime we sync from the main repository to our fork, we get a ton of new history, commits, tags etc. that muddy up our repo
- When creating a PR, github defaults to creating a PR from one of our custom branches to the main repository/assuming we want to make a contribution to the main project

***Option 2: Create a new, separate repository***

We'd create a new, clean repository from the main repo. The commit, branch, and tag history would be all our own changes.

**Downsides**

- Periodically pulling in changes from the main repository seems muddied. When we want to do this, I guess we'd create a new branch, delete all the files in it, copy/paste all the files from the main repository's master branch, then open a PR from this branch to our master?

Is there a better option or one I'm not considering?

Comment: are you making changes to the core code of the original repo, or just adding external/additional functionality without touching the original code?

Comment: Both, making changes to the original code and adding external functionality